# java generic object istance of generic class

Tags: java

I have this situation:

I receive a string from JSon file and I parse it correclty into a list, so at the end I have a list of *myObject*

I want create a generic method to search one thing into this list. I would to create a method that has how parameter one generic list of object and the Type of this object, after during the scan of the list, cast this generic object into the type that is passed.

```
List<Mission_queue> queue = gson.fromJson((String)response.get(1),listType);
Utility.CheckProperty(queue, Mission_queue.class, paramName, paramSearch);
```

My Utility method

```
public static Boolean CheckProperty(List<?> list, Class<?> classType, String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
    int idx = 0;
    for (Iterator<?> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); idx++) {
        Object obj = it.next();
        // here I want cast my generic Obj from Object to ClassType
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, how could I cast? I would create a generic method because I will have a lot of different list, but every time I need to search something inside.

Have you some ideas?

Thanks very much

Comment: What do you think you'd be able to do if you could cast from `Object` to `ClassType`?

Comment: You have to set the method on T generic type instead of using ?. In this way I can guess that the method 'next' is returning T and not Object

Comment: You can't know inside of the method what the type is going to be so it's not possible.

Comment: Have you considered the [Class.cast()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) method?

Answer (score 0):

Theres no reason to cast as the Type of Class cause you will not know in advance the methods of the class to write your code, if you use a interface you may do it, but since you are receiving String property name I think you really wanna do:

```
public static Boolean checkProperty(List<?> list, Class<?> classType, String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
    int idx = 0;
    // IMPORTANT: Do lookup before the loop to avoid loose of performance
    Field propertyAccessor = classType.getDeclaredType(propertyName);
    try {
        propertyAcessor.setAcessible(true);
    } catch(Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    for (Iterator<?> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); idx++) {
        Object obj = it.next();
        String propertyFromInsideObject = (String) propertyAcessor.get(obj);
        //Here you can use the variable that is the field you want to get
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution might has performance disadvantages but it does not need to receive any class type.

```
public static <T> Boolean CheckProperty(List<T> list, String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
    for (T object : list) {
        // Here you have an object of type T
        try {
            Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(propertyName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            String value = (String) field.get(object);

            // Use the value here
            if (propertyValue.equals(value)) {
                // TODO
            }

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(classType)` and `classType.cast(obj)` with proper Exception handling is what you are looking for.

But... if I understood right, you want to check property value by given `propertyName` and expected/acceptable `propertyValue`? is it correct?

If so maybe you do not need to cast anything and just use reflection?
to get a value there are two ways:

- simple way: use `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.BeanUtils.getProperty(Object bean, String name)`  - your object must have getters compliant to Java Beans specification.
- another way: use reflection by your own code as @marcos-vasconcelos proposed. Just a little more work to do i guess.